# how to initialize an object or a list of objects in python using an overloaded constructor

Tags: python

I am doing some exercises of python
I am writing a program where there is an Account class as shown below. I am writing a test class to initialize ten accounts with account holder's name, account holder's IBAN (account number), and account balance.

```py
class Account:

    def __init__(self, account_number_IBAN, account_holder_name,  balance):
        self.__account_holder_name = account_holder_name
        self.__account_number_IBAN = account_number_IBAN
        self.__balance = balance

    def get_AccountHolder_Name(self):
        return  self.__account_holder_name

    def get_AccountHolder_IBAN(self):
        return self.__account_number_IBAN

    def get_Balance(self):
        return self.__balance

    def createAccount(self, account_number_IBAN, account_holder_name, balance):
        return Account(self.__account_holder_name, self.__account_holder_name, self.__balance)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Account Holder Name: ", self.__account_holder_name, "\nAccount holder's ID: ", self.__account_number_IBAN, "\n Account Balance: ", self.__balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        if amount > 0:
            self.__balance += amount
        else:
            print("The amount must be greater than 0")

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if 0 < amount < self.__balance:
            self.__balance -= amount
        elif amount > 0:
            print("The amount must be greater than 0")
        elif self.__balance < amount:
            print("The amount to withdraw is less than the account balance")
```

I want to create ten accounts as a list using overloaded constructor like this as below:

```py
from Account import Account
import random


class TestAccount(Account):

    def __init__(self):
        self.account_ID_List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        self.account_Holder_Name = ["KASH", "ARRAIN", "ZAHEER", "AMJAD", "JOHN", "SURESH", "SAIIN", "CHAUDHARAIN",
                                    "SARDAR", "BLOSSOM", "DADDU"]
        self.account_balance = [0, 100, 23, 555, 10000, 0, 99, 342, 0, 0, 2131]
        self.accounts = []

        for i in range(10):
            super().__init__(self.account_ID_List[i], self.account_Holder_Name[i], self.account_balance[i])
            Account = super().createAccount(self.account_ID_List[i], self.account_Holder_Name[i], self.account_balance[i])
            self.accounts.extend(Account)
    def printAllAccountsInfo(self):
        print(self.accounts)
        # for i in range(10):

        # for index, value in enumerate(self.accounts):
        #     print(f"Index : {index}, value: {self.accounts[index].get_AccountHolder_Name()}")
        #     print(f"Index : {index}, value: {self.accounts[index].get_AccountHolder_IBAN()}")
        #     print(f"Index : {index}, value: {self.accounts[index].get_Balance()}")


obj = TestAccount()
obj.printAllAccountsInfo()
```

I expect that when the

`Account = super().createAccount(self.account_ID_List[i], self.account_Holder_Name[i], self.account_balance[i])` is called  which returns an Account object initialized with the given account holder's name, ID and initial balance then it should be saved in the python's List when I extend the list using:
`self.accounts.extend(Account)`

How I can do it?

The result is :

```
"C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe" D:\LEARNING\PYTHON_PRACTICE\Python\LIANG_BOOK\OOPS_CHAPTER_12\ACCOUNT\TestAccount.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\LEARNING\PYTHON_PRACTICE\Python\LIANG_BOOK\OOPS_CHAPTER_12\ACCOUNT\TestAccount.py", line 41, in <module>
    obj.printAllAccountsInfo()
  File "D:\LEARNING\PYTHON_PRACTICE\Python\LIANG_BOOK\OOPS_CHAPTER_12\ACCOUNT\TestAccount.py", line 34, in printAllAccountsInfo
    for index, value in enumerate(self.accounts):
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'Account' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You are extending `self.accounts`. What extending means is that you concat some other list to your original list. In your case, you are passing object as argument to `extend` function. That raises the error. What you probably meant to do is to `append` that object to your list. If you really want to use `extend` (which I don't see why would you do it here), you can probably do it like this: `self.accounts.extend([Account])`. Also, I'm not sure if inheriting as you did it is good idea and naming variable with capitalized first letter is good practice. I don't see why you need inheritance here.

Comment: BTW this is called overriding, not overloading. Overloading is a different thing.

Comment: This is not a good approach. Why not simply make a list of Account objects? This approach heavily breaks principles of OOP.

Comment: Not related to your question but your implementation of \_\_str__ is wrong. You return a tuple. You need to return str. Also, your TestAccount class is pointless. Just maintain a list of Account objects

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

> `self.accounts.extend(Account)`

expents an iterable because it is for adding all elements. You should append an account:

> `self.accounts.append(Account)`